# WHat is the correct way to retrieve feature importance from Random Forest?

Tags: r, random-forest, feature-selection

I have executed the following code:

```
  rf.fit <- randomForest(y ~ ., data=df_rf_1, ntree = 500,
      keep.forest=FALSE, importance=TRUE, sampsize = 2000)
```

I could either inspect the importance using importance(rf.fit):

```
importance(rf.fit)
                   %IncMSE IncNodePurity
locID              0.00000        0.0000
altitude          19.81292     5069.3465
afstand           31.37264     7723.1648
vluchttype        15.51977     5140.9270
type_ICAO        128.25606     4252.8332
windrichting      22.71068     1143.9057
windsnelheid      47.20290     1115.2162
temp              36.71376     1033.4310
luchtdruk         27.34953     1180.3724
luchtvochtigheid  30.92440      896.3033
neerslag           9.66072      215.8579
elevatiehoek      18.25084     2613.3396
```

or rf.fit$importance

```
                    %IncMSE IncNodePurity
locID             0.0000000        0.0000
altitude          5.8063099     5069.3465
afstand          18.3329209     7723.1648
vluchttype        9.0000239     5140.9270
type_ICAO         5.0292091     4252.8332
windrichting      0.4002848     1143.9057
windsnelheid      0.6143260     1115.2162
temp              0.4427222     1033.4310
luchtdruk         0.2986264     1180.3724
luchtvochtigheid  0.3490383      896.3033
neerslag          0.0250518      215.8579
elevatiehoek      4.3417330     2613.3396
```

As you can observe, the data in the %IncMSE is not the same. In the first output, the percentages are much larger (and add up to a value >100). However, the first method is the method I stumble upon on the web. Which of the two methods is correct?

I tried two different methods leading to different results.

You could try the following:

```
all.packages("randomForest")
library(randomForest)
rf.fit <- randomForest(mpg ~ ., data=mtcars, ntree=1000,
+     keep.forest=FALSE, importance=TRUE)
importance(rf.fit)
rf.fit$importance
```